# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'feat-bal non-95' for key 'amenity_category_mapping_amenity_name_property_id_unique'

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to run following query in laravel:

```
DB::statement("UPDATE `amenity_category_mapping` SET `amenity_name` = TRIM(`amenity_name`)");
```

However, I am receiving: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'feat-bal non-95' for key 'amenity_category_mapping_amenity_name_property_id_unique'` error.

I thing it is raising issue about duplication. Is there any way if while updating a duplicate entry is detected, I just want to delete that second entry.

Comment: you can try upsert operations. https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-upsert

Comment: Since there could be some logic involved in your application, I would not run that as a MySQL Query. I believe this is more of a maintenance task, isn't it?

Comment: Could you suggest the laravel-eloquet as well, I am ok with that as well.

Comment: If you're using eloquent then you can have the [updating event](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events) do something like `Model::where('amenity_name', $model->amenity_name)->where('id','!=',$model->id)->delete()` or something like that